# VB hidden button on form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using VB to search some data from a text file and then populate in excel. It's working. The problem is xl.visible=true makes the excel sheet to be visible at once & then the values keep on populating. I want to hide the excel till data population is complete. then make a button appear on the form which when clicked, will display the excel file.

Please help. Here is the code I'm using:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ' create an excel instance
    Dim xl = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = False
    Dim wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim sheet = wb.ActiveSheet

    ' find lines starting with any whitepace followed by MTV or MTB and capture
    ' the text after =
    Dim pattern = "(?<=\s*(MTV).*=).*"

    Dim i = 1
    Dim arg = {Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.CrLf, Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.Lf}


    If RichTextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("No input. What will I process??")

        Else
        Timer1.Start()
            For Each line In File.ReadLines(RichTextBox3.Text)
                Dim match = Regex.Match(line, pattern)
                ' check each line and fill sheet

            If match.Success Then
                sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = match.Value
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
    End If

    xl.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I think this sequence could avoid it `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application`  `xlApp.Visible = False` `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: @mehow On doing as you said the following error was observed : Warning 1 Variable 'xlApp' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: Will there always be the same number of files being uploaded or an unknown amount?

Answer (score 0):

Use Button2 to do the Excel work but remove the line: `xl.Visible = True`

Put a button on your form called Button3 (or named whatever); set Button3 property Visible = False. Then at the bottom of Button2 click event put `Button3.Visible = True`

After your Button2 gets clicked you'll have Button3 visible. In Button3 click event put `xl.Visible = True`

To make this work, you'll need to declare "xl" as a module or class variable. Just put `Dim xl as object` above your sub and remove the Dim inside your sub; that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple type `button1.Hide()` when you click on the button or something else it will then hide the button. Hope this helps you out.

Remember, `button1.Hide()` refers to the first button -  if it is the 2nd button it would be `button2.hide()`, etc.